# NoMethodError (undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I use Ruby on rails as a backend. When creating a record, such an error occurs:

> Started POST "/spr_type_events" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-06-26 15:09:31
>   +0500 Processing by SprTypeEventsController#create as JSON   Parameters: {"spr_type_event"=>{}} Unpermitted parameter:
>   :spr_type_event Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 77ms
>
> NoMethodError (undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass):
>
> app/controllers/spr_type_events_controller.rb:17:in `create'

Already I do not understand what's wrong here:

```
class SprTypeEventsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_spr_type_event, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]

    def index
        @spr_type_events = SprTypeEvent.all

        render json: @spr_type_events
    end

    def show
        render json: @spr_type_event
    end

    def create
        @spr_type_event = SprTypeEvent.new(spr_type_event_params)

        if @spr_turbodrill_type.save
            render json: @spr_type_event, status: :created, location: @spr_type_event
        else
            render json: @spr_type_event.erros, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end

    def update
        if @spr_type_event.update(spr_type_event_params)
            render json: @spr_type_event
        else
            render json: @spr_type_event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
        end
    end

    def destroy
        @spr_type_event.destroy
    end

    private

    def set_spr_type_event
        @spr_type_event = SprTypeEvent.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a trusted parameter "white list" through.
    def spr_type_event_params
        params.permit(
          :type_id,
          :date_begin,
          :date_end,
          :name,
          :comments
        )
    end
end
```

Comment: Do you have any code with you?

Answer (score 1):

At first, you have declared a variable like `@spr_type_event` but call when `save` like `@spr_turbodrill_type` it's wired, so change this e.g: `@spr_type_event.save` follow the below modified codes

```
def create
  @spr_type_event = SprTypeEvent.new(spr_type_event_params)

  if @spr_type_event.save
    render json: @spr_type_event, status: :created, location: @spr_type_event
  else
    render json: @spr_type_event.erros, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

and strong parameters method like this, you can keep the break which you code but need to add this `require(:spr_type_event)`

```
def spr_type_event_params
    params.require(:spr_type_event).permit(:type_id, :date_begin, :date_end, :name, :comments)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't initialised `@spr_turbodrill_type` anywhere in your controller for create method I think `@spr_type_event` should be there. Like in following code

```
def create
  @spr_type_event = SprTypeEvent.new(spr_type_event_params)

  if @spr_type_event.save
    render json: @spr_type_event, status: :created, location: @spr_type_event
  else
    render json: @spr_type_event.erros, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

Comment: Wow, here I am blind)